# Handling keyboard interrupt and wondering if all my variables are updated together

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

So I am wondering how exactly the keyboard interrupt relates to variable assignments. I want to know specifically if in the following 2 examples there would be a difference. The difference I am expecting is that in the second case all variables will either be updated with new values or none of them will where as in the first instance some of them may be while others may not before a given interrupt. I'm not sure of this however and that is why I am asking.

```
while True:
    try:
        a = foo()
        b = bar()
        c = baz()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print (a,b,c)

#vs.

def bam(a,b,c):
    return foo(),bar(),baz()
    
while True:
    try:
        a,b,c = bam(a,b,c)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print (a,b,c)
```

I ran the following to check things out.

```
a,b,c = 0,0,0
def increment(n):
    return n+1

while True:
    try:
        a = increment(a)
        b = increment(b)
        c = increment(c)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if a!=b or a!=c:
            print (a,b,c)
            break

#vs.

def bam(a,b,c):
    return increment(a),increment(b),increment(c)
    
while True:
    try:
        a,b,c = bam(a,b,c)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if a!=b or a!=c:
            print (a,b,c)
            break
```

It demonstrates that multiple assignment is indeed as @MichaelRuth says "non-atomic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really the question: "Are multiple assignment statements atomic?" Let's take a look at the disassembled code to see. I'll limit the code to disassemble to just the assignments for clarity.

```py
import dis
dis.dis('a=1;b=2;c=3')
dis.dis('a,b,c = 1,2,3')
```

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Multiple assignment is not atomic; however, there is only one `LOAD_CONST` operation so there is less probability that the interrupt will occur during assignment and result in a partial assignment. Said another way: there are four ops remaining in the assignments after `a` is assigned in the version with single assignment statements, but there are only two ops remaining in the assignments after `a` is assigned in the version with multiple assignment.

Please note that this disassembly was produced using CPython 3.10 on a Mac. It could be different on other platforms and other Python implementations.

Answer (score 2):

For latter code block:
If you read through [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls). It has mentions that in case of expressions first the right hand side of the equals to (=) symbol is evaluated and then it is assigned to left hand side.
If there is a function on right, first of all it will execute the block of code present in that function, here it will execute `bam(a,b,c)` which will execute `foo(),bar(),baz()` and then call the `return` statement. 
If **KeyboardInterrupt** happens before `a,b,c` are assigned values. It will throw an error because we are trying to access variable that are not yet defined properly.
So the order will be: execution of `foo(), bar(), baz()` functions -> followed by -> `return` statement of the `bam` function -> followed by -> now that we have our RHS evaluated we will proceed with assigning these return values to `a,b,c`. 
The order of assignment would be first to `a` followed by `b` followed by `c`

The first code block would be the same as you expected, it will execute one line at a time, and would error out for the variables that are not defined properly.

So overall you were right in predicting the outputs.

Comment: So let's assume a,b and c were all already set to None or something. My question is if a and or b could be updated while c remained its previous values.

Comment: Well for the first code block that is possible but for the second code block if our Right Hand Side of = symbol has been processed it won't take more time for the assigned to be processed but it will happen sequentially. So `a` will be assigned value first then `b` and then `c`.